# How to do content filtering with Apache Kafka?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a topic named mytopic. There are one producer and 2 consumer for this topic. What I need to do is filtering the messages that produces by the producer, according to their prefix. For example, if a message starts with 'a' prefix, then only the first consumer must take it. If it starts with 'b' prefix, then only the second consumer must take it.

I made a lot search, what I found is filtering messages that came from a topic and then send them to the different topics after filtering. But as said above, I need to do filtering over one topic. How can I do that in Kafka?

Comment: Why can't you use two topics? Regardless, you should take a look at Kafka Streams.

Comment: @BenWatson Yes I looked it, It provides streaming among topics. I will use it for another thing. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you can write your filter in KSQL. https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Allow both the consumers to consume all data, once you get the records **filter** them using **java stream** with the filter logic specific to the consumer.

In short, I mean just get the data as is and filter them using java code instead of doing it at Kafka Level.

**Update:**

If you want to filter at **Kafka Level**, you can use **partitions**, while sending message to kafka topic, **send messages with prefix 'a' to Partition-1, and messsages with prefix 'b' to Partition-2**.

Now, while consuming just **consume that particular partition in respective consumers**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am already doing this. What I mean can we filter the record which is going to the consumer before it reached the consumer?

Comment: Do you have any example about it? I could not figured out how to do that?

Comment: Code would be nice here ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's easy,and dont't need to write back to different topics.
'2 consumers' means 2 consumer groups or 2 consumer threads in 1 consume group?
I will talk it both.

If it is 2 consumer threads in 1 consumer group,you can use the message 'Key' field.
**Kafka send same 'Key' messages to same 'Partition'.**
For example, a message prefix 'a' with key field 'a',b message prefix 'b' with key field 'b',then Kafka will send the a message to 'Partition-1',b message to 'Partition-2'.
The consumer thread A can subscribe the specified 'mytopic-Partition-1'，thread B can subscribe 'mytopic-Partition-2' **using the 'assign' method in class 'org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer'.**

If it is 2 consumer group,just subscribe the topic and filter in the code.If unsatisfactory,use the same method above.
**The tricks is sending specific prefix message to specific 'Partition'.**
If you really want filter,maybe you can use Kafka Connect plugin.

Comment: That gives some more detail about the above answer, thanks.

Comment: But two different keys may end up in same partition. I don’t think this is a safe option if you have more keys more than the number of partitions.

Comment: I know you mean two different keys have the same hash value,but very low probability except you have too many different keys.